# Enabled only 2 dates like current date and yesterday date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there any way to enabled only current date and yesterday date in jquery datepicker, other dates of current month, previous months and coming months are disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the min and max date properties like below example :

```
$(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            minDate: '-1D',
            maxDate: '+0D',
        });
    });
```

[check the link I have created the JSFiddle example for you :](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/3605/)

Comment: thank u for support.. can you post code with jsfiddle?

Comment: @DeepakKumar there isn't any need of changeYear option.

Comment: you can't change the year.

Comment: Is this answer worked for you. If yes then please mark that solution. It will help others as well.